# bootstrap-select select all options and jinja2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2, bootstrap-select

I am trying to use the bootstrap-select package and in particular I want to use the data-actions-box="true" option which should provide a select all option. Here is my code.

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple" data-size="3" data-selected-text-format="count" data-actions-box="true" >
    {% for user in current_user.followed.all() %}
        <option>{{ user.username }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

As you can see I populate the select field with options by taking users from my database. current_user.followed gives me all users which are connected to the current_user. The code above does work if I populate the select field manually like

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple" data-size="3" data-selected-text-format="count" data-actions-box="true" >
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Barbecue</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
 </select>
```

but with my jinja2 for loop it does not work. I guess that this is a collision between jinja2 and jquery? Any idea how to do this correctly?
thanks
carl

Comment: Maybe the first thing you should check is if the template works as expected. It can be done by not applying the bootstrap-select. If the for loop still fails to populate then it is a jinja2 problem.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake, the problem was not with jinja2 at all... it was the data-size="3" option... if I remove this it works fine
carl